# Printing plot depending on variable conditions on 2 pdf pages

Tags: r, plot, sequence, traminer

I'am trying to print a plot, depending on a variable with 12 terms. This plot is the result of  cluster classification on sequences, using OM distance.

I print this plot on one pdf page :

```
pdf("YYY.pdf", height=11,width=20)
seqIplot(XXX.seq, group=XXX$variable, cex.legend = 2, cex.plot = 1.5, border = NA, sortv =XXX.om)
dev.off()
```

But the printing is to small ... so i try to print this on 2 pages, like this :

```
pdf("YYY.pdf", height=11,width=20)
seqIplot(XXX.seq, group=XXX$variable, variable="1":"6", cex.legend = 2, cex.plot = 1.5, border = NA, sortv =XXX.om)
seqIplot(XXX.seq, group=XXX$variable, variable="7":"12", cex.legend = 2, cex.plot = 1.5, border = NA, sortv = XXX.om)
dev.off()
```

But it doesn't work ... Do you know how I can ask R to separate terms' variables into two groups, so as to print 6 graphics per pdf page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to plot separately the subset of groups you want on each page. Here is an example using the `biofam` data provided by `TraMineR`. The group variable `p02r04` is religious participation which takes 10 different values.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)
bs <- seqdef(biofam[,10:25])
group <- factor(biofam$p02r04)
lv <- levels(group)
sel <- (group %in% lv[1:6])
seqIplot(bs[sel,], group=group[sel], sortv="from.end", withlegend=FALSE)
seqIplot(bs[!sel,], group=group[!sel], sortv="from.end")
```

If you are sorting the index plot with a variable you should indeed take the same subset of the sort variable, e.g. `sortv=XXX.om[sel]` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, you could post some data in order to help us reproduce what you want, maybe this helps. To plot six graphs in one page you should adjust the mfrow parameter, is that what you wanted?

```
pdf("test.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
plot(1:10, 21:30)
plot(1:10, 21:30, pch=20)
hist(rnorm(1000))
barplot(VADeaths)
...
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. It's not exactly that because in fact I have a graph generated by a single command (seqIplot), which is divided into several sub graphs (thanks to the use of the command group=XXX$variable).                                                 These are this sub graphs (belonging to the main graph launched by the command seqIplot) that I'm trying to distribute over two pdf pages.